# What is the probability that at least one of the committee members is in upper 6?

Tags: probability

One of the questions in my workbook read:

> The school bowling club has $20$ members from upper 6 and $10$ from lower 6.The club wishes to form a committee consisting of $3$ members. Find the probability that at least one of the committee members is from upper 6.

My answer is $311/609$ while the book's answer is $197/203$. Please explain to me why I did not get the same answer as the book and how to get the correct answer.

My working:

At least one of the committee members is from upper 6 means either one of the committee members is from upper 6 or two of the committee members are from upper 6 or three of the committee members are from upper 6.

Probability that one of the committee members is from upper 6
$$= \frac{20}{30} \cdot \frac{10}{29} \cdot \frac{9}{28} = \frac{15}{203}$$

Probability that two of the committee members are from upper 6 $$= \frac{20}{30} \cdot \frac{19}{29} \cdot \frac{10}{28}= \frac{95}{609}$$

Probability that three of the committee members is from upper 6
$$= \frac{20}{30} \cdot \frac{19}{29} \cdot \frac{18}{28} = \frac{57}{203}$$

Probability that at least one of the committee members is from upper 6
$$=\frac{15}{203}+\frac{95}{609}+\frac{57}{203}=\frac{311}{609}$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is not correct because your calculation does not reflect the fact that the committee selection is not ordered.  So for instance, $$\frac{20}{30} \cdot \frac{10}{29} \cdot \frac{9}{28}$$ represents the probability that the *first* member selected is from upper 6, then the following two members are selected from lower 6.  Since selected members do not have an ordering, the actual probability is $3$ times this value, since for any such selection, there are $3$ positions for the member that is from upper 6.

Similarly, the second probability you write needs to be multiplied by $3$.  But the last probability, in which all members are from upper 6, does *not* need to be multiplied by $3$ since all of them are from the same group.

Thus the corrected calculation would look like this:

$$3 \cdot \frac{20}{30} \cdot \frac{10}{29} \cdot \frac{9}{28} + 3 \cdot \frac{20}{30} \cdot \frac{19}{29} \cdot \frac{10}{28} + \frac{20}{30} \cdot \frac{19}{29} \cdot \frac{18}{28} = \frac{197}{203}.$$

However, none of this is necessary.  By far the easiest solution is to compute the complementary probability; i.e., the probability that *none* of the selected members are from upper $6$.  This occurs with probability
$$\frac{10}{30} \cdot \frac{9}{29} \cdot \frac{8}{28} = \frac{6}{203},$$ thus the desired probability that at least one member is from upper 6, is $$1 - \frac{6}{203} = \frac{197}{203}.$$